# kernel panic error

Tags: kernel

Hey guys I need a little help..
Something has gone wrong with my laptop and now When I boot into Ubuntu I get a kernel panic error.  I am even unable to boot into recovery mode.
I am trying to re-install the kernel through live CD by using following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/temp 
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/temp  # Example: sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/temp
# Run the next two commands only if you have a separate /boot partition
sudo mkdir /mnt/temp/boot
sudo mount /dev/sdXZ /mnt/temp/boot  # Example: sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/temp/boot  # (sda6 is the /boot partition)
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt/temp$i;  done
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/temp/etc/resolv.conf  # May be required to connect to the Internet.
sudo chroot /mnt/temp
```

but at the last command of `chroot` I am getting error 
`chroot: cannot run command /bin/bash': Exec format error`
I think it is happening because my versions of Live CD and installed Ubuntu are not same, but how can I find out the version of installed Ubuntu?  Please help me.  If there is any other way I will be glad to check it out!!
Thanks in advanced...

Comment: OUCH. FWIW, re-installing the kernel is unlikely to help and as you can see in that link there are a number of potential causes. You can find the version of Ubuntu with `cat /mnt/tmp/etc/issue`. We need a bit more information to help, try booting an older kernel.